# Need code for excel to populate time in a column based on value change in another column but I need this in 2 different columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am making a time tracking excel workbook for myself where I need to have start time and end time entered in 2 different columns (say col. B & C) based on change in values in other 2 different columns (say Col. E & F) and Col. D to have total time calculated. I need the time to be in hh:mm:ss format. Can someone help, please?

I have tried the following but can get only 1 column to populate the time and I need it to work in multiple columns.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A1000")) Is Nothing Then
        With Target(1, 2)
        .Value = Date
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

I know I need to just make some small changes but not sure what.
I have the data in following layout: Date Start Time End Time Total Time Nature of work Where Date is in col. A, Start Time in Col B, End Time in Col C, Total time in Col D and Nature of work in Col E. I need it to work in such a way that when I enter the date in Col A, Col B gets populated with current time (should be static in HH:MM:SS format) and when I update Col E, Col C should get updated with current time (Static in HH:MM:SS format) and then col D should calculate the total time by subtracting Col B from Col C. I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Right now, your code says "Upon a change in a cell of column A, put the current date & time into the cell in the next column". If you want to manipulate other cells in that row, you just need to change the `2` in `Target(1, 2)`. For example `Target(1, 3).Value = "End Time"` would put the text "End Time" into Column C of that row.

Comment: "based on values in 2 columns" is too vague. Without knowing what your data looks like or what the relationship between the values is intended to be, there's not really a way for anyone to answer your question.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68290017/edit) instead of adding information in a comment

Answer (score 0):

Moving comment to "Answers" section since it will be easier to read.

You're trying to make two (2) possible changes, correct?  You should be able to use a switch, assuming you only work on `Columns(4)` if `Columns(5)` has been populated, due to having different actions when `Columns(1)` & `Columns(5)` are each populated.

Something like the below should help shed some more light (untested):

```
Select Case Target.Column
    Case 1
        Cells(Target.Row,2).Value = Format(Now(),"HH:nn:ss")
    Case 5
        Cells(Target.Row,3).Value = Format(Now(),"HH:nn:ss")
        Cells(Target.Row,4).Formula = "=C" & Target.Row & "-B" & Target.Row
    Case Else
        Exit Sub
End Select
```